# Git commit is corrupted even if I removed big sized file from my PC's cloned folder

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-lfs

Please read this below context with a little patience and give your suggestion to solve the error!

I made a website https://vitspace.netlify.com/

but I am unable to commit changes because I have uploaded a file named DISCRETE MATHS.pdf With 248MB after getting this below shown error
I just removed it from my PC's cloned folder and committed again but still, it shows the same error even there is no file to commit
I've tried many ways by asking ChatGPT but nothing worked!

'''
>git push origin main: main
remote: error: Trace: 825ce91a120085366cf102abc4602ffd66724a231b8fbd6d617acc75b4b85105
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File DISCRETE MATHS.pdf is 248.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/Joelmarkjoseph/VITSPACE.git
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Joelmarkjoseph/VITSPACE.git'
'''
'''
What I've tried is
>>    git lfs untrack "DISCRETE MATHS.pdf"
>>    git reflog expire --expire=now --all
>>    git gc --prune=now --aggressive
>>    git push origin main: main
But no use I'm very frustrated with this

I'm expecting to clear the error showing
remote: error: File DISCRETE MATHS.pdf is 248.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
'''
There is no such file! I've already removed it after knowing the limit. How can I solve this?

Comment: I linked 3 duplicates out of many more with the exact same problem.